# How to suppress the initials in the references section?

Tags: biblatex

I am using BibLaTeX, and I want to customize the <strike>citation labels</strike> bibliographic entries to omit the initials of the authors, displaying only the last name and "et al."

For example, I want my citation in the bibliography to appear as "Chang et al. (2011)" instead of "Chang, Leyen S. et al. (2011)".

Here is my current setup:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, doi=false, url=false, 
isbn=false, maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=1, giveninits=false, 
uniquelist=false, uniquename=false, date=year]{biblatex}
```

However, this configuration doesn't achieve the desired result. How can I modify my BibLaTeX settings to achieve the citation style I am looking for?

Here is a sample bib entry:

```
@article{chang_supersonic_2011,
    title = {Supersonic Mass-Flux Measurements via Tunable Diode Laser Absorption and Nonuniform Flow Modeling},
    volume = {49},
    issn = {0001-1452, 1533-385X},
    url = {https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/1.J051118},
    doi = {10.2514/1.J051118},
    pages = {2783--2791},
    number = {12},
    journaltitle = {{AIAA} Journal},
    shortjournal = {{AIAA} Journal},
    author = {Chang, Leyen S. and Strand, Christopher L. and Jeffries, Jay B. and Hanson, Ronald K. and Diskin, Glenn S. and Gaffney, Richard L. and Capriotti, Diego P.},
    urldate = {2024-02-16},
    date = {2011-12},
    langid = {english},
}
```

Comment: Please edit your query to also show the bib entry in question.

Comment: @Mico, I added the bib entry as you asked.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "citation in the bibliography". Is it (a) the citation call-out in the body of the document or (b) the formatted bibliographic entry in the References section? (It's not common to refer to the formatted bibliographic entries as "citations".)

Comment: I am sorry. In my question, I mean (b), the formatted bibliographic entries.

Comment: Is there a bibliography style which requires this? Because you're basically asking to deny your reader basic information about your sources. Even a full name doesn't guarantee your reader will know who the author is, but dropping first name(s) and initial(s) entirely deliberately obscures the identity. Using `authoryear` and `uniquename=false` with this is just a recipe for confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would normally not recommend this. It's usually much nicer to have a more detailed bibliography and to credit all people involved at least with bits of their given name. But the rest of the setup looks like a last-ditch effort to save space as well, so here you go.

We define a new name format that only prints the family name and use that. Because it would look weird to only change the primary name (`sortname`) associated to the work, we also change the `default` name format that is used for most other purposes.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber, 
  style=authoryear,
  maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=1,
  giveninits=false, 
  uniquelist=false, uniquename=false,
  date=year,
  doi=false, url=false, isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson et al. (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395.]